# Replacing or removing word with Logstash filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

```
#Version: 15.01.1034.026
#Log-type: Message Tracking Log
#Date: 2018-11-27T17:00:01.234Z
#Fields: date-time,client-ip,client-hostname,etc.
```

I can drop lines start with the `#` but last line has my csv headers, I just want to replace or remove `#Fields:`  definition via logstash filter.

```
if [message] =~ /^# .*/ { drop { } }
```

What is the correct way to do that with logstash as a proper csv file to insert ES?

Answer (score 0):

You can select only need data as below, you will have new faild called `csv_fields` ad the message will `date-time,client-ip,client-hostname,etc.` as your sample data

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "(?<csv_fields>(?<=#Fields:\s)%{GREEDYDATA})" }
}
```

You can test it here https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: i need to remove first 3 lines and Replace "#Fields" character from the 4th line. The other definitions are my csv header. i dont need to match anything.

Comment: @cankaya07 it will take the needed data and set it in message field, not only match